# How to create new array deducting segments of existing array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create new array out of an existing array in Python.
I read some of already existing and similar questions but I still can not solve the problem.

For example:

I have array `A = [4,6,9,15]` and I want to create `B =[(6-4),(9-6),(15-9)]`.

I tried to do it in for loop like this:

```
deltaB=[]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    deltaB[i]=A[i]-A[i-1]
    deltaB.append(deltaB[i])
```

But that does not work... probably because I am writing code completely wrong since I'm new in Python and programming in general.

Can you help and write me code for this?

Many thanks upfront

Answer (score 3):

## List comprehension

Probably the best way to do this is using *list comprehension*:

```
[xj-xi for xi,xj in zip(A,A[1:])]
```

which generates:

```
>>> [xj-xi for xi,xj in zip(A,A[1:])]
[2, 3, 6]
```

Here we first `zip(..)` `A` (the list) and `A[1:]` the slice of the list that omits the first element together into tuples. For each such tuple `(xi,xj)` we add `xj-xi` to the list.

## The error

The error occurs because in the `for` loop, you start from 0 and stop before `len(A)`, it should be starting from 1 and stop before `len(A)`. Furthermore you cannot first assign to an index that does not exist, you need to directly append it:

```
deltaB=[]
for i in range(1,len(A)):
    deltaB.append(A[i]-A[i-1])
```